# OneNote API for sovereign network

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

I'm trying to test on the China sovereign network.

Using these 2 API endpoints for Authentication and Graph API.
https://login.chinacloudapi.cn, https://microsoftgraph.chinacloudapi.cn

```
Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphProvider.GetGraphServiceClient(tenantName, clientId, clientSecret);
graphClient.BaseUrl = "https://microsoftgraph.chinacloudapi.cn/V1.0";
...
var notebooks = await graphClient.Users[userPrincipalName].Onenote.Notebooks.Request().GetAsync();
```

This does not seem to be working for the China sovereign network. (Works fine for ordinary US endpoint)

Here's the packet dump

***Request***

> GET
>   /V1.0/users/??????/onenote/notebooks
>   HTTP/1.1
>
> SdkVersion: Graph-dotnet-1.12.0
>
> Authorization: Bearer
>   eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IlFrQ1dPOTFCcWhuMWVub0d3MmRLT3B3aXozS1ZPNnB2TV93Tjl2Vk1va0kiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6InljS3RWOG1aX0pmM25CVmJmZzRmblp1TFFSYyIsImtpZCI6InljS3RWOG1aX0pmM25CVmJmZzRmblp1TFFSYyJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL21pY3Jvc29mdGdyYXBoLmNoaW5hY2xvdWRhcGkuY24iLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3N0cy5jaGluYWNsb3VkYXBpLmNuLzljZGE1YzQ2LTk1NjItNGFhNy05NzQyLTE3MjBjZjRlMmQwZi8iLCJpYXQiOjE1Nzk3MTk1NjcsIm5iZiI6MTU3OTcxOTU2NywiZXhwIjoxNTc5NzIzNDY3LCJhaW8iOiJZMlZnWUpqeTdqN1hVOG05TExFOGZjNHJwdDVZQ2dBPSIsImFwcF9kaXNwbGF5bmFtZSI6IkNvbW12YXVsdF9UZXN0IiwiYXBwaWQiOiI2YjliNTE0Mi0xOWY4LTQ2MGUtYWNjOC02ZTU5M2MxNGI0NTYiLCJhcHBpZGFjciI6IjEiLCJpZHAiOiJodHRwczovL3N0cy5jaGluYWNsb3VkYXBpLmNuLzljZGE1YzQ2LTk1NjItNGFhNy05NzQyLTE3MjBjZjRlMmQwZi8iLCJvaWQiOiI1ZGQ0ZTM3Mi03NWVjLTRhYTEtODhkNy00ZDliOTAyZDI1ZjYiLCJyb2xlcyI6WyJTaXRlcy5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQWxsIiwiRGlyZWN0b3J5LlJlYWQuQWxsIiwiVXNlci5SZWFkLkFsbCJdLCJzdWIiOiI1ZGQ0ZTM3Mi03NWVjLTRhYTEtODhkNy00ZDliOTAyZDI1ZjYiLCJ0aWQiOiI5Y2RhNWM0Ni05NTYyLTRhYTctOTc0Mi0xNzIwY2Y0ZTJkMGYiLCJ1dGkiOiIwRS1Wdmp0WFBrLURVdUZXaFpBWEFBIiwidmVyIjoiMS4wIiwieG1zX3RjZHQiOjE1NzM0NjEzNzF9.y5QkGFjb2_EFB0oexXgdSZxbkHkKrkcc5GgpmrH0I2865LQ0vPkkK2efyJU19tEKNhkWXXADAsD76SalzSheu7hQ69sCj-HsXyRbG-Ue03KMmD2KsXRVFK-bVrjF1vJl9k5zKUeYP0rw5sjc7G33GmYh6L6iFm8y_PHg9W14JOfvCaMsvu0QXK9UTc7AWUy09L71ZVw6SGEokfayFfjqh8bkq7jI8CuvOV61tAUgmUJvIijSsl6HwoHVrMJ5D_RLLPdkOD01fN4YDkYCsleEDsgLnqXpzmtOPABzgVuyDfk-saAo4PLl-omN4OTx5-_bJjq5LM_SqTnELihSrYCkaw
>
> Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
>
> Host: microsoftgraph.chinacloudapi.cn

***Response***

> {   "error": {
>       "code": "Request_BadRequest",
>       "message": "Unexpected segment OpenPropertySegment. Expected property/$value.",
>       "innerError": {
>         "request-id": "a4cf5da0-715e-4dbd-ad1e-fd4b5e8f2134",
>         "date": "2020-01-22T19:04:31"
>       }   } }

Am I missing something when calling the API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Locke but OneNote is not supported on Microsoft Graph in China for now